# Code help: Delete files that are older than 60 days

Tags: python, python-3.x

New to Python. I'm trying to write a script that will delete files that are older than 60 days. I know that there are a bunch of ready exampels out there that are ready but I'm trying to solve it by my own. Here is my code:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

# Gets the current date and time.
dt1 = datetime.now()
dt = datetime.timestamp(dt1)
print(f"\nDate and time right now:\n{dt}")

# Changes the path.
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(f"\nCurrent path:\n{cwd}")

the_dir = "C:\\Users\\Downloads\\Test"
change_dir = os.chdir(the_dir)

cwd = os.getcwd()
print(f"\nChanged the path to:\n{cwd}\n")

# All the files in directory/path
list_dir = os.listdir(cwd)
#print(list_dir)

count = 0
#Checks when the files were modified the lastest and removes them.
for files in list_dir:
    #count = 0+1
    last_modi =os.path.getctime(files)
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(last_modi)
    print(last_modi)

    # 5184000 = 60 days
    if (dt-last_modi) >= 5184000:
        print(files)
        print("This file has not been modified for 60 days.")
        os.unlink(files)
        print(f"{files} removed.")
```

I want you guys to help me see what I have missed. In my folder/directory I have four files. Three of them are older than 6 months and 1 of the files is newly created. when I print the files in my if-statement it shows all the files and when I run the script none of the files are deleted.

Some additional stuff which I would like to add to the script would be that I print a list which shows:
These are the files which will be deleted:

file_one....

files two....

Are you sure you want to delete them? (Y or N)

I would also like to add a counter which in the end will show how many files were deleted.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Ok, You describe what You want but not what is the PROBLEM. Do You get any errors, etc ? If You want to know what You have missed maybe the codereview stack will be better ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my folder/directory I have four files. Three of them are older than 6 months and 1 of the files is newly created. when I print the files in my if-statement it shows all the files and when I run the script none of the files are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should store all the files path in a list and then check for input to proceed with delete or not.

```
now = datetime.now()
files_to_delete = []
for files in list_dir:
    #count = 0+1
    last_modi =os.path.getctime(files)
    dt_obj = datetime.fromtimestamp(last_modi)
    print(last_modi)

    # 5184000 = 60 days
    if (now - dt_obj).day >= 60:
        print(files)
        files_to_delete.append(files)
        #print("This file has not been modified for 60 days.")
        #os.unlink(files)
        #print(f"{files} removed.")

if files_to_delete:
    print("These are the files which will be deleted:\n")
    print(*files_to_delete, sep='\n')
    decision = input("Are you sure you want to delete them? (Y or N)")
    if decision.upper() == 'Y':
        for file in files_to_delete:
            os.remove(file)
            print(f"{file} removed.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I understand your code. I tried runing it on my directory and it didn't remove any file?

Comment: @Ahmed have you checked if this `if (dt-last_modi) >= 5184000` condition get `True` for some file or by printing the `files_to_delete` i.e some files found to be deleted. However I have updated my code to compare the day difference instead of timestamp. Now it would be more readable.

Comment: @Ahmed also yoh have to run this script from inside the same directory where you are checking the file modified date

Answer (score 0):

In general, it's helpful to break problems to pieces by defining functions. It makes debugging much easier and makes your code more readable.

```
#custom_delete.py
#/usr/bin/python3

import os
import shutil
import platform
import time
import datetime

count = 0                      #initiating counter variable
ts = time.time()               #getting current time
cur_dir = "/home/foo/Desktop/" #change according to your needs

'''
This function returns the absolute path of the file and its last edit timestamp.
'''

def getLastEdit(file):         
 mod_time = os.stat(cur_dir + file).st_mtime
 abs_path = cur_dir + file
 return abs_path, mod_time


'''
This function prompts a dialog and removes the file if accepted. 
Notice that its looking for files older than an hour, 
hence "3600". You can edit this function to batch remove. 
'''

def removeIfOld(abs_path, mod_time):
 try:
  if mod_time + 3600 < ts:
   user_validation = input("Remove file:" + abs_path + "?" + ("Y/N"))
   if user_validation.upper() == "Y":
    os.remove(abs_path)
    count += 1
   if count % 10 == 0:
    print("Deleted count:" + str(count))
 except Exception as e:
  print(e)

'''
Define our main process so script can run.
'''

if __name__ == "__main__":
 for file in os.listdir(cur_dir):
  removeIfOld(getLastEdit(file))
```

You can test it via terminal by saving the script as custom_delete.py and running $python3 custom_delete.py